# Нужно выводить на PictureBox файлы, выбранные в ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Столкнулся с проблемой, было у меня задание, сделать программу для просмотра изображений, выбирать расширение картинок, путь к ним, путь отображать на лейбл. Всё сделал. Дошёл до последнего пункта, "при выборе элемента в листбокс открывать его на пикчербокс". Подумал, что легко, но почесав репу понял, что не могу придумать, как это делать.

```
string fullPath = FolderBrowserDialog.FileName;
label1.Text = fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.LastIndexOf('\\'));
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.LastIndexOf('\\')));
foreach (string file in files)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
}
try
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(FolderBrowserDialog.FileName);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Не корректный файл. Выберите, пожалуйста, файл с расширением .png|.jpeg|.bmp|.gif","Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Вот этот кусочек, в котором происходит всё и сразу, подвязан на ивент нажатия кнопки(всё вместе подвязано, наверное, так нельзя, но как есть)

Answer (score 0):

В общем, чуточку пошевелив мозгами и собрав по этому поводу коллоквиум, нашёл ответ

```
foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
                    var path = Directory.GetParent(file).FullName;
                    listBox1.SelectedValueChanged += (o, ea) =>
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(path,(string)((ListBox)o).SelectedItem));
                    };
                }
```

Это награмождение работает, не идеально, но работает

Comment: Подписку на событие вынесите из цикла. И используйте аргумент `ea`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А можно чуть подробнее?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `ea` это `EventArgs`, там ничего нет. Вы перепутали с WPF `SelectionChangedEventArgs`, а здесь WinForms.